# Abstract base class for Scalar, Vector, Tensor,

Tags: c++, vector

I want to design a class `PrimitiveType` which serves as an abstract class for mathematical entities such as scalar, vector, tensor, and so on to store them in a `std::vector<PrimitiveType *> myVector` through which I can iterate. For example, having two of these vectors of identical size, say `myVector1` and `myVector2`, I want to be able to do something like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector1.size(); i++)
     myVector1[i] += myVector2[i];
```

and don't want to care whether I'm adding scalars, vectors, or tensors. Up to now, I came up with

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<class T> class Scalar;

template<class T>
class PrimitiveType
{ 
    protected:
        size_t size_;
        T *value_;

    public:
        virtual ~PrimitiveType() = 0;
        PrimitiveType & operator+=(const PrimitiveType &primitiveType) 
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < size_; i++)
                value_[i] += primitiveType.value_[i]; 
            return *this;
        }
};

template<class T> PrimitiveType<T>::~PrimitiveType() {};

template<class T>
class Scalar : public PrimitiveType<T>
{
    using PrimitiveType<T>::size_;
    using PrimitiveType<T>::value_;

    public:
        Scalar(T value = 0.0) 
        { 
            size_ = 1; 
            value_ = new T(value); 
        }
        ~Scalar() { delete value_; }
        operator T &() { return *value_; }
};

template<class T>
class Vector : public PrimitiveType<T>
{
    using PrimitiveType<T>::size_;
    using PrimitiveType<T>::value_;

    public:
        Vector(T value = 0.0) 
        { 
            size_ = 3; 
            value_ = new T[size_]; 
            std::fill(value_, size_, value); 
        }
        ~Vector() { delete[] value_; }
        T & operator()(size_t index) { return value_[index]; }
};

int main()
{   
    Scalar<double> s(3.2);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    static const size_t size = 3;

    std::vector<PrimitiveType<double> *> p = std::vector<PrimitiveType<double> *>(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        p[i] = new Scalar<double>();
        *(p[i]) += s;
        std::cout << *static_cast<Scalar<double> *>(p[i]) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but I don't think this is a very clean solution. In particular,

1) I would like to be able to use initializer lists in the child classes but get problems with dependent name lookup, e.g.

> error: ‘using PrimitiveType::size_’ is not a non-static data member of ‘Scalar’

How to realize something like `Scalar(T value = 0.0) : size_(1) , value_(new T(value)) {}`?

2) I would actually prefer to make `value_` a static array because I know at compile time what size `value_` has for `Scalar`, `Vector`, ... Of course, this does not hold for `PrimitiveType`, however, an instance of `PrimitiveType` gets never created.

Comment: This looks like an extremely complicated solution, and I'm not sure I understand its purpose. Shouldn't addition be a completely different operation depending on the type of *both* operands? I honestly don't believe that OOP is a good choice here; I cannot imagine a useful abstract operation which does not care whether it deals with a vector or a scalar. At any rate, mixing OOP and operator overloading (plus templatising it as well!) is often a good indicator that the program design should be reconsidered.

Comment: First Rule of Inheritance: don't do it. Second Rule of Inheritance (experts only): don't do it yet.

Comment: This doesn't really work. You can't, for example, multiply two arbitrary matrices.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Invoking the `operator+=` of course only makes sense if the type of the argument matches the type of the object on which the method is called. It doesn't make any sense to call `operator+=` on a second-order tensor and pass a first-order tensor (= vector). Not only does it make no sense but the function may also yield a segmentation fault (or show other non-intended behavior) because an entry which does not exist is accessed. But I think it can be ok to make it the caller's duty to make sure to pass the correct arguments.

Comment: @Puppy It is not intended to multiply arbitrarily-shaped matrices but only tensors which are fixed in size, i.e. scalars (1 component), vectors (3 components), second-order tensors (9 components, if non-symmetric), and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Complete edit because other solution was not ok.

Well, the simplest way for your problem would be to move the storage from the main class to the base class and provide accessor of element:

```
template <class C>
class PrimitiveType {
public:
    PrimitiveType & operator+=(const PrimitiveType &primitiveType) {
        if (this->_size() != primitiveType._size()) {
            throw "Incompatible type." ;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < this->_size() ; ++i) {
            this->_get(i) += primitiveType._get(i) ;
        }
        return *this ;
    }
protected:
    virtual C& _get (size_t) = 0 ;
    virtual C _get(size_t) const = 0 ;
    virtual size_t _size () const = 0 ;
};
```

Then in `Scalar` and `Vector` for example:

```
template <class C>
class Scalar : PrimitiveType <C> {
    C _value ;
public:
    Scalar (C const& c) : _value(c) { }
protected:
    virtual C& _get (size_t) = 0 { return _value ; }
    virtual C _get(size_t) const = 0 { return _value ; }
    virtual size_t _size () const = 0 { return 1 ; }
};

template <class C, int N = 3>
class Vector : PrimitiveType <C> {
    std::array <C, N> _values ;
public:
    Scalar (std::initializer_list <C> l) : _values(l) { }
protected:
    virtual C& _get (size_t i) = 0 { return _values(i) ; }
    virtual C _get(size_t i) const = 0 { return _values(i) ; }
    virtual size_t _size () const = 0 { return _values.size() ; }
};
```

**End of edit.**

For your first question, just add a protected constructor in PrimitiveType and call it from your child class:

```
class PrimitiveType {
protected:
    PrimitiveType (/* */) : _values(/* */), /* ... */ { }
};

class Scalar {
public:
    Scalar (/* */) : PrimitiveType(/* */) { }
}
```

For your second questions, add a storage type as second argument templates of primitive type:

```
template <class C, class S = std::vector <C>>
class PrimitiveType { /* */ }

template <class C>
class Scalar : public PrimitiveType <C, std::array <C, 1>> { /* */ }
```

Detailled example:

```
template <class C, class S = std::vector <C>>
class PrimitiveType {
public:
    PrimitiveType & operator+=(const PrimitiveType &primitiveType) {
        /** Same code as yours. **/
    }

protected:
    S _values ;
    PrimitiveType (std::initializer_list <C> l) : _values(l) { }
};

template <class C>
class Scalar : public PrimitiveType <C, std::array <C, 1>> {
public:
    Scalar (C const& c) : PrimitiveType({c}) { }
};
```

Comment: They won't be able to have a `std::vector` with pointers to a mix of `Scalar`s, `Vector`s, and `Tensor`s, will they? The base class for each will be different.

Comment: @JosephMansfield if the vector is of type PrimitiveType it would work

Comment: @NathanWride No because you have multiple `PrimitiveType` with different template instanciation.

Comment: @Holt Sorry I see now

Comment: @JosephMansfield I added a big edit to my post, should be ok now, thx for you comment.

Comment: @Holt It is actually a good idea to invoke a `get()` method from the base class because each child can implement it depending on its own container type. A more effective solution, however, would probably be to use iterators because one then avoids a function call in each loop iteration. Imagine the base class storing `T *first_` and `T *last_` which are pointers to the first and last element of the container, then it is possible to replace the implementation of `operator+=` by something like `for (T *it = first_; it != last_ + 1; it++) *it += ...`.

Comment: @Holt Your advice to add a protected constructor in `PrimitiveType` and call it from the child class works like a charm...

Comment: @Marcel I don't think there is any overload using `get()` method because most compiler will inline these functions. Iterator may be a good idea but there isn't a generic iterator for all container so you may get the same problem that before.